# How to show/hide components using angular4?

Tags: javascript, angular, eventemitter

i have 2 components so i have expand functionality where if user click one component should take full screen so in that case i want to hide other component and vice versa.Component is expanding and overlaping on other. How to achieve this using angular2 + ?

search.component.html

```
    <div class="card card-outline-info" [ngClass]="{'expandWidget':isClassExpanded}" (click)="onClickMe($event)" >
      <span class="pull-right fa fa-compass"  style="font-size:25px"></span>
      <div class="card-header bg-info"><h5>Detail</h5></div>
      <div class="card-block">
            <p>TExt</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

search.component.ts

```
@Output() open: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
 onClickMe(event) {
     event.target.classList.add('expandWidget'); // To ADD

    if(event.target.classList.contains('expandWidget')){
        event.target.classList.remove('expandWidget');
    }

      this.isClassExpanded = ! this.isClassExpanded;
      this.open.emit(true);
 console.log('You are my hero!',event);
}
```

detail.component.html

```
<div class="card card-outline-info" [hidden]="hideContent>
  <div class="card-header bg-info"><h5>Live Stream/Search Results</h5></div>
  <div class="card-block">
    <p>Text</p>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

detail.component.ts

```
onClicked= (value:boolean) => {
   alert("Outside of component "+value);
   this.hiddenContent = value;
 }
```

main.component.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <app-search></app-search>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <app-detail></app-detail>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Create a class .dispN{display:none} and toggle it using [ngClass]

Comment: where , can you please provide code snippet or answer i been struggling with this for hours..display None will hide all including the one user is working at no ?

Comment: Can u provide a full html template to get it implemented which is parent of these two component?

Comment: I added more to question so inside main i have two components , now user can make each of these components full screen and small so once comp1 is full screen i want to hide comp2 and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Given that I understood your question correctly, here's one way to solve the problem:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-dguqkn?file=app%2Fdetail.component.ts

What is going on is that you the search component emits an event to the parent component (app.component) which changes the value of `detailHidden` which is bound to a Input decorator which we call hidden in this example. In the detail component we then listen on changes using the ngOnChanges lifecycle hook.

You could also potentially simply just do a `*ngIf` in the app.component itself if it's just to be toggled.

Hopefully this leads you on the correct track nonetheless

Comment: How i could have same functionality on both of cards ?

Comment: @hussain What do you mean?

Comment: I mean this will be part of both cards, user can click on search or detail to expand it and hide the one that is not clicked

Comment: @hussain I've updated the playground link, do you mean like this?

Comment: I understand its hiding the card block but it should hide complete component when you click on text of each content in your example , i tried to implement your code functionality only works on one component.